# django reverse to dynamic id

Tags: django, url, dynamic, reverse

After i ran a view without a template, id like to reverse back to the previous view.
However this view had a dynamic part in it, and now i cant figure out how i could pas that argument with my reverse:

My urls:

```
url(r'^building/(?P<building_id>\d+)/$', views.building, name='building'),
url(r'^building/upgrade/(?P<building_id>\d+)/$', views.building_upgrade, name='building_upgrade'),
```

My view:

```
@login_required
def building_upgrade(request, building_id):
    building = get_object_or_404(Building, pk=building_id)
    if building.town.user != request.user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    create_upgrade(building)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('building'))
```

How can i send the building_id back with the reverse, so it knows what url to load?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
reverse('building', kwargs={'building_id': building_id})
```

Comment: actually, this is                                                 `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('building', kwargs={'building_id': building_id}))`

Answer (score 0):

```
url = reverse('building', args=[building.id])
```